# Why does my custom template CalendarDayButton not listen to PropertyChanged?

Tags: wpf, xaml, calendar, wpf-controls

I've created a custom control based on Calendar that also implements. It's functionality is that it can color code days based on if that day is present in a Observable Collection.

I've created a template for the calendar's CalendarDayButton component (by copying the Calendars source code), where i added a rectangle which i can use to display a background color. The rectangles fill property is bound to my DataContext and my custom calendar via a multi binding and using a converter.

This works well when the DataContext of the CalendarDayButton changes, but it seems to completely ignore all changes done to my observable collection. Meaning, when i add or a remove a day, the calendar does not update it's look. I had a breakpoint in the converters Convert function. It gets called when the calendar loads, but not when i add days.

I've also made a breakpoint in my calendar's OnPropertyChanged function, and it's PropertyChanged is allways null. I've also tried to make my ObservableCollection into a DependencyProperty, and using single Bindings to both object. No change. It seems like binding things to the rectangle did not create a listener.

Right now i change the date of the calendar to DateTime.Min and then back again, which causes the data context of each button to be updated as a work around to this issue, but it is ugly.

#### I would like to understand this behavior better. I am also interested in a proper solution to updating the colors of my calendar day buttons triggerd by a change in a collection.

Here is my custom calendar:

```
namespace Lekstuga
{
    public class ColouredCalendar : Calendar, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public DependencyProperty DoneMarkedDaysProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("DoneMarkedDaysAttribute", typeof (ObservableCollection<DateTime>),
                                        typeof (ColouredCalendar));

        public ObservableCollection<DateTime> DoneMarkedDaysAttribute
        {
            get { return (ObservableCollection<DateTime>) GetValue(DoneMarkedDaysProperty); }
            set { SetValue(DoneMarkedDaysProperty, value); }
        }

        static ColouredCalendar()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ColouredCalendar), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ColouredCalendar)));
        }

        public ColouredCalendar()
            : base()
        {
            SetValue(DoneMarkedDaysProperty, new ObservableCollection<DateTime>());

            DoneMarkedDaysAttribute.Add(new DateTime(2013, 05, 01));
            DoneMarkedDaysAttribute.Add(new DateTime(2013, 05, 02));
            DoneMarkedDaysAttribute.Add(new DateTime(2013, 05, 03));
        }  

        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public void AddNextDay()
        {
            var greenDays = DoneMarkedDaysAttribute;
            var nextDay = greenDays[greenDays.Count - 1].AddDays(1.0d);

            DoneMarkedDaysAttribute.Add(nextDay);

            OnPropertyChanged("DoneMarkedDaysAttribute");
        }

        public void Refresh()
        {
            var curDate = DisplayDate;
            DisplayDate = DateTime.MinValue;
            DisplayDate = curDate;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my converter:

```
namespace Lekstuga
{
    class DayToColorConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        private SolidColorBrush myGreenBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
        private SolidColorBrush myIndigoBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Indigo);

        public DayToColorConverter()
        {

        }

        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var tmp = (values[0] == null);
            if (tmp == false)
            {
                tmp = (values[1] == null);
            }
            if (tmp == true) return null;

            var day = ((DateTime) values[1]).Date;
            var markedDays = (ObservableCollection<DateTime>)values[0];

            if ( markedDays.Contains(day) )
            {
                return myGreenBrush;
            }

            
            return null;
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

And finaly the relevant bit of my CalendarDayButton template:

```
...
                        <Rectangle x:Name="TodayBackground" RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1" Opacity="0" Fill="#89B8FF"/>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="SelectedBackground" RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1" Opacity="0" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="Background" RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1" Opacity="0" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="DoneMarkingBackground" IsHitTestVisible="False" Visibility="Visible" >
                            <Rectangle.Fill>
                                <Binding Converter="{StaticResource DayToColorConv}" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:ColouredCalendar}}" Mode="OneWay" />
                            </Rectangle.Fill>
                        </Rectangle>
                        <ContentPresenter
                                x:Name="NormalText"
                                HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                Margin="5,1,5,1">
                            <TextElement.Foreground>
                                <SolidColorBrush x:Name="selectedText" Color="#FF333333"/>
                            </TextElement.Foreground>
                        </ContentPresenter>
                        <Path x:Name="Blackout" Opacity="0" Margin="3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Fill="#FF000000" Stretch="Fill" Data="M8.1772461,11.029181 L10.433105,11.029181 L11.700684,12.801641 L12.973633,11.029181 L15.191895,11.029181 L12.844727,13.999395 L15.21875,17.060919 L12.962891,17.060919 L11.673828,15.256231 L10.352539,17.060919 L8.1396484,17.060919 L10.519043,14.042364 z"/>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="DayButtonFocusVisual" Visibility="Collapsed" IsHitTestVisible="false" RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1" Stroke="#FF45D6FA"/>
...
```

Comment: Try having your calendar implement `INotifyCollectionChanged`, listen for the `ObservableCollection`'s `CollectionChanged` event and pass it on in `OnCollectionChanged`. Also, possibly try changing the name of your `DoneMarkedDaysProperty` to reflect the actual name, `DoneMarkedDaysAttribute`(Property).

Comment: Hi Nate! I've done as you suggested. My property and atribute now have the same name and ColouredCalendar implements both CollectionChanged and PropertyChanged. Unfortunatley both my PropertyChangedEventHandler and NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler are null :(

Comment: Hmmmm... Are you binding directly to the control itself or to the underlying ObservableCollection? Are you ever resetting your Collection (like, overwriting it) without calling OnPropertyChanged?

Comment: The code i posted is the code that i am using. I tried both, binding to my ColouredCalendar and to DoneMarkedDays observable collection. The collection is created and filled in the constructor, i don't overwrite it. I have a button in my GUI that calls AddNextDay(), but as you can see that only add one element to it. Thanks for your continued interest in this subject :)

Comment: I ran into this same problem. Thanks for the workaround.